# Fastest way to find closest double/float in a sequential array

Tags: arrays, performance, search

Suppose we have an array of values like so:

```
[0] = 1.2
[1] = 2.4
[2] = 2.7
[3] = 3.3
etc.
```

And we want to find the closest match, such that a f(2.5) = 1. In other words, a search for "2.5" will yield the index which equals 2.4 since that is the closest match

For small arrays- it's not a big deal, just loop from the first index and compare to difference of next vs. previous. But for large arrays this is a waste- since it would be much better to start from the end if the target value appears near there.

Comment: Does this relate to a particular language? If so, could you please tag  the question with it.

Comment: Any language which supports Arrays and Floats really :)

Comment: OK. The general answer by @OscarBralo is sufficient.

Comment: Frankly it turns out I didn't need it since a linear search was fast enough for my case, but considering the upvotes and lack of other responses at this point, I'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It´s sorted? If it´s sorted you can use **Binary Search** in order to find it!

The performance in huge arrays will be great! O(logN)

Some info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm